# How to return both a dict and a file by an endpoint using FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, fileresponse

I need to return both a dict and a file using FastAPI. But I can only achieve so far returning a file. Could you please show me how to do it? Thanks.

### Expected Usage

#### Primary usage

The primary usage is that, I will use an external Python app to call this API by (`requests.post`)

```py
out_data, zip_file = requests.post(url, json={"input_data": "some"})
# And then,
# 1. Save the zip_file to local drive
# 2. Post analysis of the out_data
```

#### Nice-to-have usage

As with FastAPI, I can use its built-in docs directly from the web-browser. Like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/` --> `Try it out` --> See the `out_data` in the response part and download the zipfile directly from the browser.

### Example code (not working)

Here is example code that you can please start with.

```py
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

CUR_DIR = Path(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class OutData(BaseModel):
    name: str
    value: float


@app.post("/", response_class=FileResponse)
async def run(input_data: str) -> tuple[OutData, FileResponse]:  # This type hint gives an Error by FastAPI.
    out_data = OutData(name="A Name", value=10)
    # Here is just make the current folder a zip-file.
    shutil.make_archive(str(CUR_DIR), "zip", str(CUR_DIR))
    zip_file = CUR_DIR.parent.joinpath(f"{CUR_DIR.name}.zip")
    return out_data, FileResponse(path=zip_file, filename=zip_file.name)
```

Comment: What do you expect your browser to do with that? Download a zip file or use the JSON for something useful? How you solve this will depend on what the use case actually is. Generally you'll have to base64 encode content and include it a JSON field if you want to combine the response into a single response format. If you want to give the user both the metadata and the zip-file, include a JSON file inside the zip archive with the necessary data.

Comment: @MatsLindh, thanks for your comments. I have added the section Expected Usage in my question.

Comment: Another way to accomplish the same goal would be to save the file to disc (probably with something like a UUID as filename) and add a separate `GET` endpoint to download the file. Then in your `POST` endpoint, you can add `"file_url": <your generated filename here>` to the JSON response.